# In space $C[0,1]$ find distance from point $x(t)=t^{2}+1$ to the subspace $L_{1}=\{x\in C[0,1]: x(0)=0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Here is the full question

6.
(a) In space $C[0,1]$ find distance from point $x(t)=t^{2}+1$ to the subspace $L_{1}=\{x\in C[0,1]: x(0)=0\}$.

(b) In space $C[0,1]$ show that $L_{2}=\{x\in C[0,1]:\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt=0\}$

is a linear subspace and find the distance from point $x(t)=t-\frac{1}{2}$ to this subspace.

(c) Show that in space $C[0,1]$ the distance from point $x(t)=t$ to the above subspace $L_{2}$ cannot exceed $\frac{1}{2}$.

I’m not really sure how to interpret the subspace in this problem (a). Can someone please give a hint on how to start this?

Comment: It looks like the question is to find the distance between function $t \rightarrow t^2+1$ to the vector subspace of continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ which verify $f(0)=0$. But the distance is not specified (or is $L_1$ the distance rather than the subspace name?).

Comment: My professor gave us this question exactly how I posted it, on an exam. I think $L_1{1}$ is the subspace name. Up to this point in class we would have only covered up to chapter 2.10 in kreyszigs functional analysis, not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I posted the full question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it if unspecified, the usual distance between two elements $x,y \in C[0,1]$ is $$\| x-y\| = \sup_{t\in [0,1]} \vert x(t)- y(t)\vert.$$ The distance from an element $x \in C[0,1]$ to a subset $Y\subset C[0,1]$ is then $$\text{dist}(x,Y) =\inf_{y\in Y} \| x-y\|,$$ which, intuitively, measures something like the distance from $x$ to the closest element in $Y$ (though there may be no “closest” element). Here, the subspace $L_1$ is the set of all continuous functions which are $0$ at $t= 0$. Clearly $x(t) = t^2 +1$ is not in this set.

For any $y \in L_1$, we have $$\|x-y\| \ge \vert x(0)-y(0)\vert = \vert 1-0\vert = 1,$$ which shows that $$\text{dist}(x,L_1) \ge 1.$$ in the other hand, letting $z(t) = t^2$, we see that $z\in L_1$, and thus $$1= \|x-z\|  \ge \inf_{y\in L_1} \|x-y\|= \text{dist}(x,L_1)$$ so we conclude $$\text{dist}(x,L_1)=1.$$

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'am pretty sure that (a) is meant the following way: $C[0,1]$ is endowed with the maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. $L_1$ is a subspace of $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, thus $L_1$ carries the maximum norm, too (the symbol $L_1$ is a bit missleading as it could be mixed up with $L^1$). Setting $y(t):=t^2+1$ the distance in question is
$$
{\rm dist}(y,L_1):= \inf_{x \in L_1} \|y-x\|_\infty.
$$
For each $x \in L_1$ we have $y(0)-x(0)=1$, hence $\|y-x\|_\infty \ge 1$. Thus ${\rm dist}(y,L_1) \ge 1$. Now try to find a special function $x \in L_1$ (easy to guess) such that $\|y-x\|_\infty =1$. Then you know that the infimum is a minimum and ${\rm dist}(y,L_1) = 1$.